# sql select from where

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables created in MYSQL.First is called "cars" and second is called "pages".
Pages is related to cars through cars_id. I am trying to select only those pages that are actually related to cars with following PHP function:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM pages WHERE cars_id = {$row["id"]}", $connect);

    $row is a variable - $row=mysql_fetch_array()// fetched from cars.
```

And I got this kind of error:

Database connection failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one query instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pages.*
FROM
    pages JOIN
    cars ON cars.cars_id = pages.cars_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if your example is correct, then one issue is that you need a space after the `*` and before the `FROM`

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE cars_id = ". $row["id"], $connect);`

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors.

1. `*FROM` needs a space b/w `*` and `FROM`.
2. `{$row["id"]}` was breaking the sequence of query.

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE cars_id = {$row['id']}", $connect);